# SQL query to fetch maximum number of the repeated field

Tags: mysql

I need to write the sql query to fetch the maximum "version" of the row of "title":

```
version      title           
1.1           article1
1.3           article3
1.1           article2
1.7           article1
1.8           article3
1.6           article2
```

output should be: maximum version of article 1 ,2 3 are respectievly, 1.7,1.6,1.8

```
version      title           
1.7           article1
1.6           article2
1.8           article3
```

how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
      MAX(varsion),
      Title
FROM 
      MyTable 
GROUP BY Title
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT title, MAX(Version)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY title
```